# Aligning the overflowing text

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to centre align the name of the book, it works fine for short names but not for long names. This is my first-time making an app.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
        child: Row(
      children: [
        Image.network(image, height: 200, width: 125),
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  title,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 26,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  author,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  rating.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

[Here is how it looks currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drIMA.png)

Comment: using `textAlign: TextAlign.center` inside Text widget should fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it out,

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
        child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Image.network(image, height: 200, width: 125),
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 150,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  title,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 26,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  author,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  rating.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
```